# C++ template Partial Specialization Member Function; Am I doing right?

Tags: c++, c++11, template, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to improve my C++ template metaprogramming skills. From my understanding, I can't partially specialize a function(either member function or not). So, I need to define another class that can be used as template class, which enables us partially specialize template argument.

So, In order to check my understanding, I've wrote a simple code. It uses general template class and partially specialized template class to deal with various types. (I've tested this code using gcc 4.8 / clang 3.4 / MSVC 2015) It would give a result as follows:

> Generic
>
> Specialization for std::string
>
> Specialization for bool
>
> Specialization for integral type

Am I doing write using class templates? I need a review for this. Any comment would be helpful.

```cpp
// a.hpp
#ifndef A_HPP
#define A_HPP
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

// declaration & implementation for bar_impl::bar
template <typename T, typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
struct bar_impl
{
    static void bar(const T& input)
     {
        (void)input;
        std::cout << "Generic" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct bar_impl<T, std::false_type, std::true_type, std::false_type>
{
    static void bar(const T& input)
    {
        (void)input;
        std::cout << "Specialization for integral type" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct bar_impl<T, std::false_type, std::true_type, std::true_type>
{
    static void bar(const T& input)
    {
        (void)input;
        std::cout << "Specialization for bool" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T, typename T1, typename T2>
struct bar_impl<T, std::true_type, T1, T2>
{
    static void bar(const T& input)
    {
        (void)input;
        std::cout << "Specialization for std::string" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Foo
{
    template <typename T>
    void bar(const T& input);
};

template <typename T>
void Foo::bar(const T& input)
{
    bar_impl<
        T,
        typename std::is_same<T, std::string>::type,
        typename std::is_integral<T>::type,
        typename std::is_same<T, bool>::type
    >::bar(input);
}

#endif // A_HPP

// b.cpp
#include "a.hpp"

int main()
{
  Foo foo;

  foo.bar(Foo());
  foo.bar(std::string());
  foo.bar(bool());
  foo.bar(int());
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you've written does work, and you seem to understand all the concepts (e.g., "you can't partially specialize function templates"), and your coding style (indentation and whatnot) seems fine.

---

Well, one coding-style improvement: You need those `(void)input` casts to shut up compiler warnings about unused parameters... in C. But in C++ you don't need those casts; what you do instead is, if you're not going to use a parameter, just *don't give it a name*.

```
static void bar(const T&) { ... }
```

---

However, your code doesn't really match any common TMP patterns — which is probably just because you're noodling around, learning, instead of trying to solve a specific problem.

If you just wanted to produce the same output with less code, you would do this:

```
struct Foo
{
    template<class T> auto bar(const T&) -> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_integral<T>::value>
    {
        std::cout << "Generic" << std::endl;
    }

    template<class T> auto bar(const T&) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>
    {
        std::cout << "Specialization for integral type" << std::endl;
    }

    void bar(bool)
    {
        std::cout << "Specialization for bool" << std::endl;
    }

    void bar(const std::string&)
    {
        std::cout << "Specialization for std::string" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.bar(Foo());
    foo.bar(std::string());
    foo.bar(bool());
    foo.bar(int());
    return 0;
}
```

That is, your code is equivalent to providing two *overloads* of `foo.bar`, plus a couple of mutually exclusive templates (one for integral types and one for other types). The specific overloads for `bool` and `std::string` will take precedence over the templates.

---

Alternatively, you could use tag dispatch, as follows. (But I don't recommend it in this case because it turns out to be surprisingly subtle. Replace the second instance of `std::true_type` with `...` and watch that overload silently drop out. I'm not actually sure why.)

```
struct Foo
{
    template<class T> void bar_impl(const T&, ...) {
        std::cout << "Generic" << std::endl;
    }

    template<class T> void bar_impl(const T&, std::true_type) {
        std::cout << "Specialization for integral type" << std::endl;
    }

    void bar_impl(const std::string&, ...) {
        std::cout << "Specialization for std::string" << std::endl;
    }

    void bar_impl(const bool&, std::true_type) {
        std::cout << "Specialization for bool" << std::endl;
    }

    template<class T> void bar(const T& input)
    {
        bar_impl(input, std::is_integral<T>{});
    }
};
```

---

Maybe the best approach would be to use two non-interacting levels of tag dispatch: first, is `T` integral? and second, what is `T` exactly?

```
template<bool IsIntegral> struct BarImpl {
    template<class T> static void bar(const T&) {
        std::cout << "Generic" << std::endl;
    }
    static void bar(const std::string&) {
        std::cout << "Specialization for std::string" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<> struct BarImpl<true> {
    template<class T> static void bar(const T&) {
        std::cout << "Specialization for integral type" << std::endl;
    }
    static void bar(bool) {
        std::cout << "Specialization for bool" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Foo {
    template<class T> void bar(const T& input) {
        BarImpl<std::is_integral<T>::value>::bar(input);
    }
};
```

Comment: Regarding `(void)input;` to silence compiler: your advice is sound, but `clang` and `g++` both complain about unnamed parameters when warning levels are cranked up.  I typically compile with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` for example.

Comment: "clang and g++ both complain about unnamed parameters when warning levels are cranked up" — I've checked Clang 3.0 through 3.9, and GCC 4.3.6 through 5.2.0, and no they don't. If you're getting a compiler warning, post it here or as a question on StackOverflow and I bet someone will sort it out for you.

Comment: Hmm.  Just checked for myself and you're right.  I thought I had encountered that situation recently, but it's clear that I remembered it wrong.  Thanks for correcting me!  (Ah -- it's for C but not C++ that this comes up.)